# React how to position a component next to another one

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a component that I would like to display next to some text fields, but it isn't being displayed properly.

**This is how it is currently displaying**

[image: This is how it is currently displaying]

The PieChart still has to render the blue section, but I believe it is overlapping with the bottom of the form. It should be able to render all 3 parts.

This is all under one functional component by the way. The PieChart is down towards the bottom and all of the code is under one div.

```
return(
    <>
        <div>
            <h1 style = {{textAlign : "center", backgroundColor : 'grey'}}>Calorie Counter</h1>
            <h1 style = {{textAlign : 'center', fontSize : '22px'}}>DAILY INTAKE:  {currentCals} / {calorieIntake} | 
            PROTEIN : {currentProtein} / {maxProtein} | FATS: {currentFats} / {maxFats} | CARBS : {currentCarbs} / {maxCarbs} </h1>
             
        
            
            <form style = {{display : 'flex', flexDirection : 'column', borderTop : '1px solid black' , borderRight : '1px solid black', 
            borderBottom : '1px solid black', width : '230px', marginTop : '30px'}} 
            onSubmit = {(event) => calculateCaloricIntake(event)}>       
            
            <h1 style = {{fontSize : '15px'}}>CALCULATE CALORIC INTAKE</h1>
            
            <FormControl required>
                <InputLabel>Sex</InputLabel>               
                    <Select value = {sex} id = 'selectSex' onChange={(event) => setSex(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150} }>
                        <MenuItem value = 'Male'>Male</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = 'Female'>Female</MenuItem>
                    </Select> 
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl>
                <TextField required placeholder = "Age" onChange = {(event) => setAge(event.target.value)} inputProps = {{maxLength : 2}} sx ={{width : 150}} ></TextField>
                <TextField required placeholder = "Weight" onChange = {(event) => setUserWeight(event.target.value)} inputProps = {{maxLength : 3}} sx ={{width : 150}}  ></TextField>         
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl>        
                <InputLabel>Height in Feet</InputLabel>
                <Select value = {heightFeet} onChange = {(event) => setHeightFeet(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150}} required>
                    <MenuItem value = {5}>5</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {6}>6</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl>
                <InputLabel>Height in Inches</InputLabel>
                <Select value = {heightInches} onChange = {(event) => setHeightInches(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150 }} required>
                    <MenuItem value = {1}>1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {2}>2</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {3}>3</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {4}>4</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {5}>5</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {6}>6</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {7}>7</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {8}>8</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {9}>9</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {10}>10</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value = {11}>11</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
                 
            <FormControl>
                 <InputLabel>Activity Level</InputLabel>
                    <Select required value = {activityLevel} onChange = {(event) => setActivityLevel(event.target.value)} sx = {{width : 150}}>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.2}>Sedentary</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.375}>Slightly Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.55} >Moderately Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.725}>Very Active</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value = {1.9}>Extremely Active</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
            </FormControl>

            <Button sx = {{justifyContent : 'left'}} type = "submit">Submit</Button>

            </form>
            
            
            <FormControl sx = {{ display : 'left', flexDirection : 'column', alignItems : 'right', borderTop : '1px solid black', borderRight: '1px solid black', borderBottom: '1px solid black', width : '230px', height : '300px', marginTop : '30px'}}>
                <form onSubmit = {(e) => submitForm(e)} required>
                    <h1 style = {{fontSize : '15px'}}>ADD FOOD</h1>
                    <TextField placeholder='Calories' sx = {{width : '200px'}} id = "calories" required ></TextField>
                    <TextField placeholder='Protein' sx = {{width : '200px'}} id = "protein" required ></TextField>
                    <TextField placeholder='Fats' sx = {{width : '200px'}} id = "fats" required></TextField>
                    <TextField placeholder='Carbs' sx = {{width : '200px'}} id = "carbs" required></TextField>
                    <Button type = "submit" > Add Food</Button>
                </form>

            </FormControl>

            <PieChart data = {pieData} radius = '10' center={[50, 1]} ></PieChart>
            
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: You can use flexbox. Wrap all your form (all left side contents) in one div. And chart in another div. Then giv flex css to parent

Comment: So I tried that and it didn't work. The chart is still being rendered as shown. Just to confirm, you wanted me to put everything all left-aligning components into a FlexBox (I used a Box from MUI) and set the display to flex, then put the chart into its own div. Does that sound right?

Comment: No. You need to put all left-aligning components into one div. Chart in another div. And wrap these two divs in flexbox

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I had the PieChart outside of the Box. Now that I put it inside, it works perfectly. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: That's the main purpose of Flex Box. It needs one container call Flex Container and number of child called Flex Items which will be automatically arranged depending on viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox